# BinaryFormatter in .netcore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

BinaryFormatter compatibility issue in .NET framework and .NET core 2.2

We have exiting code that convert `byte[]` to DataSet using BinaryFormatter in .NET framework 4.0 class library (a common library for multiple projects). Now we added a new asp.net core 2.2 project and try to use the same existing library, fortunately we resolve all dll issues but not able to call BinaryFormatter Deserialize method.

Below is the common code:

```
        BinaryFormatter oBinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (MemoryStream oMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Deserialize the byte array into a DataSet and return it to the caller
            oMemoryStream.Write(abData, 0, abData.Length);
            oMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            return (T)(oBinaryFormatter.Deserialize(oMemoryStream));
        }
```

```
Inner Exception: 
      Type 'System.String' is not deserializable.
Source:
      System.Private.CoreLib

Stack Trace:
         at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, Boolean check)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at System.Data.DataSet.DeserializeDataSetSchema(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, SerializationFormat remotingFormat, SchemaSerializationMode schemaSerializationMode)
   at System.Data.DataSet..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, Boolean ConstructSchema)
   at System.Data.DataSet..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

Comment: Don't use BinaryFormatter in the first place. It was frowned upon even back in the .NET 4.0 days for security reasons. Are you sure you're running on the correct runtime? Check the [Binary Serialization in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization) which also includes some pretty strong warnings. That said, `System.String` *is* serializable - as long as it's the *correct* System.String. The BinarySerializer writes and reads the complete type, including versions etc. Did you try to read something generated by 4.0?

Comment: BTW why use BinaryFormatter for a DataSet? That type was built to serialize to XML from the start. If you care about size, compress the file. Word and Excel files for example are ZIP packages containing XML files. They're actually smaller than the older `doc` and `xls` formats that didn't use compression. Right now, instead of serializing the *data* held by a DataSet, the code is serializing the Dataset's internal structure

Comment: can any suggest which version of .net framework BinaryFormatter work well with .net core 2.2 BinaryFormatter.

Comment: I just explained that BinaryFormatter is a *bad choice in .NET 4.0 itself*. Where did the file you try to deserialize come from anyway? .NET 4.0 perhaps? Have you tried serializing and deserializing a DataSet in .NET Core only ?

Comment: I agree, need to upgrade .Net 4.0 to its latest one but this is the challenge here we need to find some alternate to resolve this. I can't say this my client that it is a bad choice.

Comment: How did you produce the bytes? I can't reproduce any problem. I can write a DataSet to a file and read it back again without problems. Did you create the binary file in .NET 4.0?

Comment: And yes serialization and deserialization in .net core working fine. Only compatibility issue there. I serialize an object in .net framework 4.5.1 and tries to deserialize in .net core 2.2.

Comment: [Looks there's an issue about this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35629) without any further information. The problem is that the metadata stored in there It's definitely not ready for 3.0. I can't stress enough that BinaryFormatter is discouraged - that means that people aren't intersted in fixing problems with it and MS employees have higher priorities in .NET Core itself. If you check what the output file contains you'd be surprised to find ... the dataset's XML, schema plus some binary type data. BinaryFormatter is *more* verbose than XML

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce a problem with this code :

```
var ds=new DataSet();
var table=new DataTable("Moo");
table.Columns.Add("Field1",typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Field2",typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add("Value1",1);
ds.Tables.Add(table);
ds.AcceptChanges();
var bf = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var stream=File.OpenWrite("test.bin"))
{
    bf.Serialize(stream,ds);
}

using (var stream2=File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
{
    var ds2=(DataSet)bf.Deserialize(stream2);

    Debug.Assert(ds.Tables[0].TableName==ds2.Tables[0].TableName);
    Debug.Assert(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count==ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
    Debug.Assert((string)ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field1"]=="Value1");
    Debug.Assert((int)ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field2"]==1);

}
```

Viewing the generated file shows contains the dataset's schema and XML plus type metadata , making it *more* verbose than an XML file alone:

```
              NSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   System.Data.DataSet   DataSet.RemotingVersion   XmlSchemaXmlDiffGramSystem.Version            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Moo">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string" msdata:targetNamespace="" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:int" msdata:targetNamespace="" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>   ‚<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet><Moo diffgr:id="Moo1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Field1>Value1</Field1><Field2>1</Field2></Moo></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram>   System.Version   _Major_Minor_Build    _Revision           sion           
```

That's *1.3KB* to save **99 bytes** of text. Writing the same using a GZipStream would produce 82 bytes :

```
using(var gs=new GZipStream(File.OpenWrite("text.gz"),CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    ds.WriteXml(gs);
}
```

Creating a file in .NET 4.x and reading it in .NET Core doesn't work yet though. There's even a [Github issue about this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35629) that isn't fixed yet.

Using [BinaryFormatter is discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8) due to security and compatibility issues. This class can deserialize anything, including unexpected or malicious types, based on the file's contents. That's what causes this compatibility problem too - the deserializer produced a new `System.String` that doesn't match the .NET Core runtime's types.

There are more mundane problems too - adding or removing a property can cause compatibility issues because the type created by BinaryFormatter won't match the type used by the rest of the application. The issue is described in [Version Tolerant Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization).

I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a cross-framework fix for this. The type is unpopular, actively discouraged and rarely used which means that there will be few volunteers to fix it. Core team employees in the meantime have higher priority issues like gRPC and stabilizing popular stacks like WinForms and WPF.